# Kinetic energy when $F(t)$ graph is given

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, momentum

[image]

The very basic problem here is that the point where this graph ends is ambiguous. I mean, what is the corresponding $y$-value for the point whose $x$-valu is  $4.5s$? Then I think we should find the area, then that will be the momentum, so use $\frac{p^2}{2m}$, as mass is given. So if theres any error in this, pls let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that you're supposed to assume the graph of force versus time is a straight line. If so the equation for $F(t)$ is easy to calculate because you know the force at $t$ = 0 and $t$ = 3s. The change in momentum is equal to the impulse, which is indeed the integral of $F(t)dt$.

Comment: The problem is with 4.5 s. i can see the linearity, and will calculate the areas o these triangles, but i need complete information as to what the extent of the graph is, ie to what y value.

Comment: Assuming the graph is linear, then at $t$ = 4.5s $y$ is -2N. If the force falls by 4N in 3 seconds, then in the following 1.5s it will fall another 2N. Or have I misunderstood what you're asking?